# C# newbie: how to know the meaning of a variable in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, variables, lambda

I'm new in a company, using C# (I'm used working with other languages), and I just encountered a Lambda expression in the code, so I'm trying to understand how this works, but the explanation on [the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) is far from being clear:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",   
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };  

    Console.WriteLine("Example that uses a lambda expression:");  
    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);  
    foreach (var sD in shortDigits)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(sD);  
    }  
}
```

When looking at the definition of "digits", I only see the content, but I can't understand why `index` is indeed the index of the string. Let me explain you what I mean, by replacing the name of that variable by `something`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",   
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };  

    Console.WriteLine("Example that uses a lambda expression:");  
    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, something) => digit.Length < something);  
    foreach (var sD in shortDigits)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(sD);  
    }  
}
```

=> How can I know that the meaning of `something` is the index and not another property of `strings[]`?

Relevant question: can I add more to this list of variables (why/why not)?

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",   
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };  

    Console.WriteLine("Example that uses a lambda expression:");  
    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, var1, var2, ...) => digit.Length < var1);  
    foreach (var sD in shortDigits)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(sD);  
    }  
}
```

=> This seems not to compile, there is a syntax error, with following message: `Delete 'Func<string,bool>' does not take 3 arguments`. Why `bool`? `index` is not a Boolean, but an integer. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot add more arguments, because the LINQ method `Where` has an exact definition of what kind of functions it can accept

Comment: Do you understand Extension Methods and Overloads? Because you need to understand what [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx) is here

Comment: You can see definition of [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Where` clause accepts expression parameter which belongs to extension method.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I was indeed not aware of extension methods. This is already explaining a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When looking at the definition of "digits", I only see the content, but I can't understand why index is indeed the index of the string.

It's because of the overload of `Where` that's being used.

`index` is a *parameter* in the lambda expression - the lambda expression is being converted into a `Func<string, int, bool>`.

From the [documentation from this overload of `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__), the `predicate` parameter:

> A function to test each source element for a condition; the second parameter of the function represents the index of the source element.

The parameter value is provided by the code that *calls* the delegate.

You don't get to decide arbitrarily how many parameters the lambda expression has - you have to provide a lambda expression that can be converted to the delegate type specified as the `Where` method parameter. You can have just one parameter (for the value) or two (for the value and the index) because the method is overloaded.

Comment: @Dominique: It sounds like really what you need to do is read up on LINQ at this point. It's too big a topic to be discussed just in comments, or even in a single SO question/answer.